# How to send data from CBV form to a template CBV?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to send the POST data from a CBV form to other CBV.

I use the valid_form method to get the info by form.cleaned_data and then i apply in this method some custom methods. 
But I cant send the result to the other view.

Also I tried put an action in the html sending to the other template and then grab the data but I cant.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

from .forms import QuoteForm
from .models import SmgQuotesTable
from .quotes import Quotes


class QuoteFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'core/home.html'
    form_class = QuoteForm
    success_url = 'quotes'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        couple = form.cleaned_data['couple']
        age = form.cleaned_data['age']
        kids = form.cleaned_data['kids']
        #query_filter = Quotes().planSelector(couple, kids, age)
        #obj = SmgQuotesTable.objects.filter(composite='Ind. Junior (H25)')
        return super(QuoteFormView, self).form_valid(form)


class QuoteListView(ListView):
    model = SmgQuotesTable


    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(QuoteListView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset #

        print(queryset)
        return queryset
```

home.html

```
{% block content %}
<style>label{display:none}</style>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'quotes-list' %}">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block py-2" value="Cotizar">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import QuoteFormView, QuoteListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', QuoteFormView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('quotes/', QuoteListView.as_view(), name='quotes-list'),
]
```

I expect to grab the name, email, couple, age and kids values in the QuoteView and apply the Quotes method so i can print the result in the quotes.html

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'TemplateView' has no attribute 'get_queryset'

Comment: I change the view to a ListView but now i have the follow error:
Method Not Allowed (POST): /quotes/
Method Not Allowed: /quotes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it.

In **views.py** replace the **form_Valid** method in the form view with  the **get_query** method in the ListView. 
With the **self.request.GET()** I get the info and pase it to the custom quot method. 
Then i return the filtered information with the result.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

from .forms import QuoteForm
from .models import SmgQuotesTable
from .quotes import Quotes


class QuoteFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'core/home.html'
    form_class = QuoteForm
    success_url = 'quotes'



class QuoteListView(ListView):
    model = SmgQuotesTable

    def get_queryset(self):
        r_get = self.request.GET
        d_get = {'name': None , 'email':None , 'couple': None, 'age': None, 'kids':None ,}

        for value in d_get:
            d_get[value] = r_get[value]

        query_filter = Quotes().planSelector(d_get['couple'], d_get['kids'], d_get['age'])


        queryset = super(QuoteListView, self).get_queryset().filter(composite=query_filter)
        return queryset
```

In **home.html** have to change the POST method to a **GET** method, because the list view dont allow POST. 
Adding in the  the **action** to the ListView template I send the data in the form to takeit with the self.request.GET in the get_queryset() method.

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Cotizador{% endblock %}

{% load static %}


{% block headers %} 
    <h1>Cotizador</h1>
    <span class="subheading">Cotiza tu plan!</span>
{% endblock %} 

{% block content %}
<style>label{display:none}</style>
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'quotes-list' %}">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block py-2" value="Cotizar">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Finaly i put the information in the **smgquotestable_list** using the object_list and the properties of the model.

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Cotización{% endblock %}

{% load static %}


{% block headers %} 
    <h1>Cotización</h1>
    <span class="subheading">Cotización</span>
{% endblock %} 

{% block content %}
{% for item in object_list %}
<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap"></div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col">SMG01</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG02</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG10</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG20</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG30</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG40</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG50</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG60</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG70</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{ item.composite }}</th>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg01 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg02 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg10 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg20 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg30 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg40 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg50 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg60 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg70 }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```